# How to transpose a csv file using jupyter?

Tags: python, csv, jupyter, transpose

**Disclaimer, I am a beginner in coding so please go easy, thanks in advance**

How do you transpose the  data before saving  the data to a csv file using python in jupyter?

Here is my code:

```
import csv

Col1 = "Product Name"
Col2 = "Product Image Is Thumbnail - 1"
Col3 = "Product Code/SKU"
Col4 = "Product Description"
Col5 = "Price"
Col6 = "Cost Price"
Col7 = "Product Image File - 1"
Col8 = "Product Image File - 2"


mydictionary={Col1:[], Col2:[], Col3:[], Col4 :[], Col5:[], Col6:[],  Col7:[], Col8:[]}
csvFile = csv.reader(open("wedding.csv"))
for row in csvFile:
  mydictionary[Col1].append(row[2])
  mydictionary[Col2].append(row[6])
  mydictionary[Col3].append(row[4])
  mydictionary[Col4].append(row[11]) 
  mydictionary[Col5].append(row[7])
  mydictionary[Col6].append(row[8])
  mydictionary[Col7].append(row[9])
  mydictionary[Col8].append(row[10])


print (mydictionary)

with open('test.csv', 'w') as csv_file1:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file1, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for key, value in mydictionary.items():
       writer.writerow([key, value])``
```

Comment: If you'd loaded the data into a 2d `numpy` array, `transpose` would be trivial. 
 `zip` is a handy way of doing something similar with lists, e.g. `list(zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6]))`.

Comment: Without a [mcve] people probably won't play around with your code and suggest improvements.  Does this code run as is, or is there some error? or wrong results.  Where is this 'transpose' supposed to fit?

Answer (score -1):

You're building your data object incorrectly. CSV is rows of data, so your best option is to create an array of rows and then write that out. Something like this:

```
import csv

# First row is the title row
rows = [(
    "Product Name",
    "Product Image Is Thumbnail - 1",
    "Product Code/SKU",
    "Product Description",
    "Price",
    "Cost Price",
    "Product Image File - 1",
    "Product Image File - 2"
)]

csvFile = csv.reader(open("wedding.csv"))
for row in csvFile:
    # add a row of data transposing positions as desired
    # NOTE: the double parenthesis are intentional, we're appending a tuple to the array  
    rows.append((row[2], row[6], row[4], row[11], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10]))

print(rows)

with open('test.csv', 'w') as csv_file1:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file1, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in rows:
        # write out each row
        writer.writerow(row)
```